# Could not buffer video data and stream it using libvlc

Tags: c++, video-streaming, audio-streaming, libvlc

I am trying to buffer audio and video data and read it from buffer using Libvlc in c++ code. 
My OS version is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit,   LibVls Version: 2.2.2-5.

I want RV24 or RV32 to work with its raw data. Using them I do not have any video data, but I have audio data. I saw the analogous problem [here](https://stacks1.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/lib-vlc-avframe-width-or-height-is-not-set/)  also I don’t receive any data in cbVideoPostrender nor int the cbVideoPrerender functions. The question is why i do not have video data? The code should be similar to the one in [here](https://stacks1.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/lib-vlc-avframe-width-or-height-is-not-set/). Also one can find the code example in  [github](https://github.com/aleksas/libvlc-stream-grabber)

```
int StreamGrabberSetMedia(VlcStreamGrabber * pGrabber, libvlc_media_t * pMedia, bool paceControl)
{
    char vcodec[] = "RV32";
    char acodec[] = "s16l";
    char pszOptions[1024] = {0};
    libvlc_event_manager_t * pEventManager = NULL;

    if (pGrabber == NULL || pMedia == NULL) return VLC_ENOITEM; 

    sprintf_s( 
        pszOptions,
        1024,
        ":sout=#transcode{"
             "vcodec=%s,"
             "acodec=%s,"
             "threads=2,"
        "}:smem{"
            "%s,"
            "audio-prerender-callback=%lld,"
            "audio-postrender-callback=%lld,"
            "video-prerender-callback=%lld,"
            "video-postrender-callback=%lld,"
            "audio-data=%lld,"
            "video-data=%lld"
        "}",
        vcodec,
        acodec,
        (paceControl ? "time-sync" : "no-time-sync"),
        (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*) &AudioPrerender,
        (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*) &AudioPostrender,
        (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*) &VideoPrerender,
        (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*) &VideoPostrender,
        (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*) pGrabber,
        (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*) pGrabber
    );
}
```

I am new in this field and I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the question? Please provide the relevant C++ code snippet as a [mcve].

Comment: Why i do not have video data, using RV24 and RV32 the video prerender and postrender functions does not work

Comment: Please post the relevant code as a [mcve] instead of linking to 3rd party sites. As-is it is unclear what you are asking and what the problem is.